# How do i bind a DropDownList using Entity Framework 6 Database-First Approach

Tags: entity-framework, razor, binding, dropdownlistfor

When i try to load the page with my DropDownList i get an error "

```
    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'FBChecklist.Server'
```

In the autogenerated model (Server.cs) i have **manually** added the SelectListItem as below :

```
    public partial class Application
{       
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    public string ServerIp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ApplicationId { get; set; }
    **public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Applications** { get; set; }
}
```

This is my default table structure in SqlServer :
**Server table**
int ServerId
nvarchar(50) ServerIp
int ApplicationId

and the DropDownList binds from 
**Application table**
int ApplicationId
nvarchar(50) ApplicationName

and the generated model :

```
    public partial class Application
   {
   public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
   public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
   }
```

In the repository(ServersService.cs) i'm retrieving the data as below :

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetApplications()
    {
        using (var db = new AppEntities())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> applications = db.Applications.AsNoTracking()
                .OrderBy(n => n.ApplicationName)
                    .Select(n =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = n.ApplicationId.ToString(),
                        Text = n.ApplicationName
                    }).ToList();
            var apptip = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = null,
                Text = "--- select application ---"
            };
            applications.Insert(0, apptip);
            return new SelectList(applications, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
```

And then in the Controller i have wired up as :

```
    // GET: Servers/Create
   public ActionResult Create()
   {
       var apps = serversService.GetApplications();
       return View(apps);
   }


   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ServerIp,ServerName,ApplicationId")] Server server)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           serversService.AddServer(server); ;

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }

       return View(server);
   }
```

For now it appears from my research there is no direct way to add properties such as SelectListItem to the autogenerated model in Database First. Any assistance on how i can achieve this using Database First approach or at least refactor the way i have implemented my code. The only thing i have seen yet that can be added to this partial class is Data Annotations.

For context this is how my view looks :

```
                                             <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-facebook">Application</label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <span class="input-icon">
                                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.ApplicationId, new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Country" })
                                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ApplicationId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add properties that only exist for the view, then use a view-model :

```
public class ServerViewModel
{
public ServerViewModel(Server server)
{
    ServerId = server.ServerId;
    ServerIp = server.ServerIp;
    ApplicationId = server.ApplicationId;
}

public ServerViewModel()
{
}

public int ServerId { get; set; }
public string ServerIp { get; set; }
public int? ApplicationId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Applications { get; internal set; }

public void UpdateModel(Server server)
{
    server.ServerIp = ServerIp;
    server.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
}
```

}

And in the view i have passed on the view model also instead of my Database-first model :

```
@model ServerViewModel
```

Controller :

```
private void PopulateLookups(ServerViewModel model)
    {
    model.Applications = serversService.GetApplications();
    }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
var model = new ServerViewModel();
PopulateLookups(model);
return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ServerViewModel model)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    PopulateLookups(model);
    return View(model);
}

var server = new Server();
model.UpdateModel(server);
serversService.AddServer(server);

return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```